# Alternate to Join command

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is there any other way to join two tables apart from using the following:

1. Select A.Id,A.Name,B.City from Table A join Table B on A.Column1=B.column1
2. Select A.Id,A.Name,B.City from Table A,Table B where A.Column1=B.column1
3. Select A.Id,A.Name,(select City from Table B where A.Column1=B.column1 ) from Table A

I heard of some other way or keyword with starts with "C".

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Define what you mean by "join"?  It can narrowly mean `join` syntax or more broadly refer to using one of the underlying `join` algorithms.

Comment: It's not different join algorithms, it's alternate syntax to join, that too part from the 3 possibilities which I have mentioned

Comment: @Durgaprasad Beware, the third one is wrong. It produces a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is cross apply and outer apply, I found it thanks

Comment: Which is called a "lateral join"

Answer (score 1):

you may heard CROSS JOIN which is the same as ANSI JOIN.
So the following 2 statements are identical:

```
Select A.Id,A.Name,B.City from Table A,Table B where A.Column1=B.column1 
Select A.Id,A.Name,B.City from Table A CROSS JOIN Table B where A.Column1=B.column1
```

Comment: Nope it's not cross join. It doesn't have join syntax in it and it will have some other keyword other than join which starts with "C"

Answer (score 0):

So, the options are:

- Option #1 is a typical join we use today.
- Option #2 is an old syntax for a join. It still works, but discouraged today for a myriad of reasons.
- Option #3 is not a join, and is not equivalent to the other two. In fact, it produces a different result.

Comment: Got it, I just gave example to not to get that answer. The one I was searching for is cross apply and outer apply